# Hosting WPF controls in Winforms

Tags: wpf, winforms, controls

My Application is developed using WinForms. Is it possible to host the WPF `DataGrid`, `Button`, `ListBox`, `ComboBox` etc in WinForms User Controls?

Comment: What have you tried?  It's much easier for the community to provide help if you make an attempt then come with more targeted questions about a problem you're having.  Yes or no questions aren't very constructive (See the first two sections of the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq)   For example, I don't really know anything about WinForms or WPF controls, but a quick Google search gave me a bunch of links that look relevant enough to answer this question.  Here was the first on the list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

Comment: @MattDavis, Microsoft might be a more worthy target of your criticism, since the article you linked to is in regards to composite controls, and WPF Learner's question was not regarding composite controls.  My hunch is that the information in your MSDN link is relevant to other controls as well, not just composite controls, but Microsoft is not holding that article out as being relevant to this question.  If Microsoft did their job, WPF Learner probably wouldn't be asking this here.  It looks like 90% of the reading in that link is irrelevant.  Microsoft is burying the info in wasteful writing.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible using the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control in Winforms and hosting WPF content inside of it.

Comment: To add to this, it can be awfully slow.. I had to add some WPF components on a Legacy WinForms program.. What I did was load the ElementHost Asynchronously which helps performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mix WinForm and WPF unless absolutely necessary. Though, Microsoft has provided the way to use WPF control in WinForm and vice-versa but it doesn't always give good result. WF and WPF renders the controls in different ways and you may face multiple issues including performance and UI flickering depending on the way they have been used.

If you really want to use WPF control in WF then use ElementHost control.

```
ElementHost.Child = wpfControl;
```